# Which FileShare option is used with FileInfo.OpenRead method?

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.fileinfo

On .NET Framework documentation says that when I use `FileInfo.OpenRead` method a read-only `FileStream` is created but, which `FileShare` option is internally used?

Once I've opened the file is read or write locked?

Comment: `FileShare.Read` is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look in [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/fileinfo.cs,419) reveals that it is

```
FileShare.Read
```

This setting is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx) to

> allow[s] subsequent opening of the file for reading

Comment: Wow I didn't know reference source, it'll help me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.openread(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_2):

> This method returns a read-only FileStream object with the FileShare
>   mode set to Read.

Comment: It's true, I don't know how I didn't see it on the remarks section, my fault :(

Comment: I'd do if I could, I just started to use Stack Overflow as an "active" user, so I don't have enough reputation ^^U But you've my gratitude